# cbind multiple dataframes, that are stored in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing 20 dataframes, all with the same number of rows. I want to combine them into one dataframe using `cbind`.

Insted of doing `combined_df = cbind(mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], mylist[[3]]....)`, I though perhaps there is a shorter way to do it, I tried `combined_df = cbind(mylist[1:20])`, however that didn't do the job it just made this weird output:

```
[1,] data.frame,49
[2,] data.frame,25
[3,] data.frame,21
```

how can I do it without repeating the same code?